# Help with Visualforce PieChart

Tags: apex, visualforce, charts

ChartController:

```
public class DonutChartController {
public List<PieWedgeData> getPieData() {
    Id userId = UserInfo.getUserId();
    User loggedInUser = [Select Id, Email, ProfileId From User Where Id = :userId];
    Integer ConApp = 0, InProcess = 0;             

    ConApp = [Select Count() from Loan_New__c where LoanStatus__c = 'Conditionally Approved' ];
    InProcess = [Select Count() from Loan_New__c where Loanstatus__c = 'In Processing' ];            

    List<PieWedgeData> data = new List<PieWedgeData>();                
        data.add(new PieWedgeData('Conditionally Approved', ConApp));
        data.add(new PieWedgeData('In Processing', InProcess));        
    return data;        
}
// Wrapper class
public class PieWedgeData {

    public String loanStatus{ get; set; }
    public Integer loanCount { get; set; }

    public PieWedgeData(String loanStatus, Integer loanCount) {
        this.loanStatus = loanStatus;
        this.loanCount = loanCount;
    }
}
}
```

Visualforce Page

```
<apex:page controller="DonutChartController" title="Count by Status">
<apex:chart height="450" width="550" data="{!pieData}" background="#F5F5F5">
    <apex:legend position="right"/>
    <apex:pieSeries dataField="loanCount" labelField="loanStatus" donut="0" highlight="true" >              
    <apex:chartLabel display ="middle" orientation = "vertical" font="bold 12px Helvetica"/>
    </apex:pieSeries>     
</apex:chart>
```

Output:

[image]

How can I change the highlighted view, and also is it possible to Display Count in the box and data on the image and Vice versa. Let me know if that is possible, thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I suggest you work through the available combination of attributes in the various chart components and see if you can find a combination that best fits your needs. The components are a compromise between ease of use and flexibility so not everything is possible.

For example, adding:

```
<apex:chartTips width="200"/>
```

will make sure the tooltip text fits within the tooltip light blue background color.

And:

```
<apex:chartLabel field="loanCount"/>
```

will display the count as the label.

Comment: Thanks Keith, the chartTips worked but not the ChartLabel, because it is displaying LoanCount on both chart and legend data. Is there any way I can Display Label on the Legend data and Count on Pie chart, let me know, thanks.

Comment: @Sfdclearner Not AFAIK. That is why all I could suggest is to work through the combinations of attributes in case it is possible.

Comment: got it, `public PieWedgeData(String loanStatus, Integer loanCount) {            
            this.loanStatus = loanStatus + ' [' + loancount + ']';
            this.loanCount = loanCount;            
        }`... I added this in Class it gave me the Output the way I was looking for

Comment: @Sfdclearner Glad you got it sorted.